# SQL IN operator equivalent in Firestore

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I'm making some experiments using Firestore and Flutter. I have a good SQL background, and this No-SQL situation is entirely new for me.

Here's my problem:
I have a `users` collection, each document in it has some descriptive fields and a `friends` field, which is an array of references to other `users` documents:

```
{
    name: "Bob",
    friends: ["ref1","ref2"]
}
```

I'd like to fetch Bob's friends, but I don't know how.

In SQL I'd use the `IN` operator, doing something like

```
SELECT user
FROM usersCollection
WHERE ref in ('ref1','ref2')
```

Clearly, I've invented the names just for the sake of clarity.

I couldn't find anything online about this, and I'm starting to think this might not be the correct way of doing something like this.

I have no code tests right now because I'm wandering in the dark and haven't found anything online (perhaps I'm looking for the wrong thing).

Thanks in advance!

Comment: With noSQL you have to fetch all the related documents yourself. There's no join or similar, you do it in multiple requests with code.

Comment: Are you telling me to iterate through Bob's friends and query the collection each time for each friend?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what you need to do

Comment: Allright... Would it be better if I stored some duplicated infos directly into Bob's friends? Is this a good denormalisation strategy? I'd need this just to show friends names in a list.

Comment: That's a possibility. You'll probably want to setup a firebase function that watches modification on the users to replicate the modifications on all copies.

Comment: You'll probably want to make "friends" a collection instead of a field too BTW. So that you can load the user without all of its friend list.

Comment: You're right! Nice tip thanks